# How to get a list of files and folders of just those folders listed in a text file into a list file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I created a batch file to export all files, folders, and subfolders in a specified directory to a text file. What I need is to list specific files with subfolders from a text file which includes their path. Batch file will list files and subfolders only included in this text file. For instance, I need to export to a text file only files under those folders as in the input text file.

```
C:\Users\Username\Documents\test1
C:\Users\Username\Documents\test2
C:\Users\Username\Documents\test3
C:\Users\Username\Documents\test4
```

Thanks in advance.

Edited to add more details; normally, we use this command to list all files under a directory:

```
dir > output.txt
```

I want to apply another approach. I'd like to list files under particular directories only that a text file will include those specific directory paths.

This is text file:

```
C:\Users\Username\Documents\myfolder1
C:\Users\Username\Documents\myfolder2
C:\Users\Username\Downloads\yet another folder
```

Although there are many other folders inside Documents and Downloads, only files under folders whose paths listed in my input text file will be listed. Then, all subfolders and files of `myfolder1`, `myfolder2`, and `yet another folder` will be sent to an output text file.

Comment: Murray, check out the command "tree", I believe it's what you're looking for, but maybe there's a better way of doing it with "dir", but I'm don't know much about the windows command line

Comment: Hi, LuRsT. Actually, this is not something I am looking for. I need to output files by using of a path list in the text file.

Comment: It is also possible to read the directories from a text file by using __FOR__ which can also search recursively for files in a directory tree like for usage directly in a cmd window `for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %I in ("ListFile.txt") do for /R "%~I" %J in (*) do echo %J`. Get help on command __FOR__ by executing in a command prompt window `for /?`. If you want to see a list of commands, run in cmd window `help`.

Comment: Hi Mofi, thank you very much for your reply. Your offers sound very well. Your second comment is exactly what I want to do. However, I couldn't manage to adapt the code. What's wrong with it? for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %I in ("C:\Users\Username\Documents\Listfile.txt") do for /R "%~I" %J in (*) do echo %J

Comment: @Murray if you use this line inside a batch file, double each `%`: `%%I`, `%%~I` and `%%J`. (this is one of the rare cases, where syntax for command line and for batch files are different)

Comment: @Mofi and Stephan; I tried it as you suggested. Nothing happens. I added >output.txt in order to export search results into the text file. I located batch file and Listfile in the same directory. I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: ah - you don't want "all pdf files", but "all lines in a file"?  `for /f "delims=" %%a in (listfile.txt) do echo %%a`

Comment: @Stephan I added `>output.txt` at the end of your code, but no files or subfolders are listed in the output.txt  . I also added some details upon Mofi's request. Thank you all for your kind interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read a file containing folder names and list files in each of those folders and its subfolders:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do dir /s /b "%%a\*"
```

Adapt the `dir` switches and file mask to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This very simple batch file can be used for this task:

```
@echo off
rem First check existence of folders list file and exit
rem batch file execution if this file does not exist.

if not exist "%UserProfile%\Documents\FoldersList.txt" goto :EOF

rem Delete output list file if already existing from a previous execution.
rem The error message output on file not existing is suppressed by
rem redirecting it from handle STDERR (standard error) to device NUL.

del "%UserProfile%\Documents\OutputList.txt" 2>nul

rem For each folder path in folders list file run the command DIR to output
rem in bare format all files and folders including hidden files and folders
rem in the folder and all its subfolders with redirecting the output written
rem to handle STDOUT (standard output) to the output list file with appending
rem the new lines at end of the list file. The list file is automatically
rem created on first line written to the output list file.

for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%I in ("%UserProfile%\Documents\FoldersList.txt") do dir "%%~I\*" /A /B /S >>"%UserProfile%\Documents\OutputList.txt"
```

Just a list of files with no folders is produced with replacing **DIR** option `/A` by `/A-D` which means any attribute except attribute directory. That would be the same as using for last command line with the difference that files with hidden attribute set are not output by inner **FOR**:

```
for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%I in ("%UserProfile%\Documents\FoldersList.txt") do for /R "%%~I" %%J in (*) do echo %%J>>"%UserProfile%\Documents\OutputList.txt"
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `rem /?`

See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).

Comment: Hi @Mofi Thank you so much. Your solution works as described. I can't thank you enough. I voted for your and Stephan's solutions. You both are awesome coders!